# To bake a chicken in the oven

Tags: baking, food-safety, chicken

Is it safe to cook a chicken for 20 minutes at 250 degrees, Then take it out of oven and put back in refrigerator and then cook it thourghly the next day.

Comment: I stongly encourage you *not* to do this. You will get your chicken in the danger zone where bacteria multiply best for a really long time. Find more on the risky temperature range here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Oh, and gina, could you please add the unit for temperatures in future questions? We are an international site and some will automatically think '°C', others '°F' - can be really confusing! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate of the linked question (since you're not technically leaving the food at room temp) but I agree with Stephie that this is a *very bad idea*.